# wrapper on footer links blocks

Tags: magento-1.9

im new one magento, in trying to change my footer, manly the background, basically im tring to add a block with a email, address and location info above my footer blocks links. I add this block inside a phtml of newsletter form. The only issie is that i have inside of a container with a specific width, but i need to make a wrapper out of footer-container, because i need to give another background color. I tryed wrapping the links block ("mypackage/page/template/links.phtml"), but i notice that the block "Account" and "CONNECT WITH US" is not from the links.phtml, how can i make what im trying to do?

I leave here how it is:
[image]

How i want to be
[image]